# A Formula of $E(X^n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The problem 1.1 on p.46 of *Stochastic Processes, Sheldon M. Ross, The Second Edition* said:

> If $X$ is nonnegative with distribution $F$, then
> $$
> E[X^n]=\int_0^\infty{nx^{n-1}\bar{F}(x)\mathrm{d}x}.
> $$

Here $\bar{F}(x) := 1-F(x)$.

Here's my solution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E(X^n)
&= \int_0^\infty{x^n\mathrm{d}F(x)}\\
&= -\int_0^\infty{x^n\mathrm{d}\bar{F}(x)}\quad(F(x)+\bar{F}(x)=1)\\
&= -\biggl.x^n\bar{F}(x)\biggr|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty{\bar{F}(x)\mathrm{d}x^n}\\
&= -\biggl.x^n\bar{F}(x)\biggr|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty{nx^{n-1}\bar{F}(x)\mathrm{d}x}\\.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I'm almost there, but it suffices, if all above are right, to show
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}{x^n\bar{F}(x)}=0,\tag{1}
$$
which I'm afraid is wrong.

Can someone figure out my problem, or just show that (1) is actually right?

Comment: I am pretty sure this has been answered multiple times. Did you use [ApproachZero](https://approach0.xyz/search/)?

Comment: In fact, $Ef(X)=\int_0^{\infty} f'(x)\overline F (x) dx$ as an easy consequence of Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: @snoop Interesting web! It's useful to me, but I still haven't known my problem.

Comment: @tryinghardtobecomeagoodprslvr Thank you, but I'm just wondering why I'm wrong, or why formula (1) is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation $(1)$ is correct, assuming that $E|X^n|<\infty$. For any $x>0$, if you start with the inequality between random varaibles
$$
x^n{\bf 1}(X>x)\le |X|^n,\qquad (x>0)
$$
and take expectations, you get
$$
x^n\overline{F}(x)\le E|X^n|\qquad (x>0)
$$
Furthermore, you have $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^n {\bf 1}(X>x)=0$, almost everywhere in the probability space. Assuming $E|X^n|$ is integrable, the dominated convergence theorem lets you upgrade the almost-everywhere limit to a limit of expectations, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^n\overline{F}(x)=0$ as well.

Comment: Can this statement be a corollary? "If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable with $E[g(X)]<\infty$ for some continuous function $g$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}{g(x)\bar{F}(x)}=0$."

Comment: I do not know. I believe it is true by the same reasoning as long as $g$ is monotonic. You could ask that as a separate question.